# Dealing with Missing Column Name Error When Accessing Data Files for Graph Generation

Tags: multiple-file-upload, data-filtering

`I calling data files with specific names. My graph is based on that columns name. One of the files don't have the column name because of the error from the source.

When i run my code, because that column name don't exist. it shows and error.

```
CRD_4_Date=[] CRD_4_Data=[]

for i in range(0, len(loans)):if  loans['Time'][i] < datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 14, 11,40): if loans['Time'][i] > datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 0,0):


loans_Date.append(loans['Time'][i])
loans_Data.append(loans['Bank_1'][i])`
```